# AdMob показ рекламы в авиарежиме

Tags: java, android, ios, admob

Мне показали приложение в App Store в котором реклама показывается даже в авиарежиме, причём каждый раз разная (речь о Rewarded Video и Interstitial). Как это возможно реализовать?

Comment: закешированые ролики

Comment: Как это можно сделать на Android?